# как нажать на кнопку на сайте через консоль JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть кнопка:

`<a href="/index.php?whats-new/profile-posts/163765/page-2" class="pageNav-jump pageNav-jump--next">Вперёд</a>`

Как "нажать" её через консоль?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('.pageNav-jump--next').click();
```